# Failure to write NSString to file on iPad

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, ipad

I'm using a text file to save the changes made by a user on a list (the reason that I'm doing this is so that I can upload the text file to a PC later on, and from there insert it into an Excel spreadsheet).  I have 3 data structures: A NSMutableArray of keys, and a NSMutableDictionary who's key values are MSMutableArrays of NSStrings.

I iterate through these data structures and compile a file string that looks much like this:

```
(Key);(value)\t(value)\t(value):\n(Key);(value).. .so on.
```

SO, onto the actual question:  When I attempt to save it, it fails.  I'm 99% sure this is because of the file path that I'm using, but I wanted backup to check this out.  Code follows:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithString:[self toFileString]];
if(![fileString writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL]){
    NSLog(@"File save failed");
} else {
    // do stuff
}
```

(Code above is re-copied, since the actual code is on a different computer.  It compiles, so ignore spelling errors?)

I tried using NSError, but I got bogged down in documentation and figured I might as well ask SO while trying to figure out how to properly use NSError (might be a little bit of an idiot, sorry).

99% sure it's the NSArray *paths line that's tripping it up, but I don't know how else to get the documents directory.

Edit:  Problem solved, and one final question:  If I save it to the App's document directory, where can I go after I close the app to see if it saved properly?  If it works like I think it does, isn't it sandboxed in with the app's installation on the simulator? (i.e. no way of checking it)

Comment: If you have a second question, make it a second question!

Yes, the file written will be buried in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/...

Comment: I didn't think it was really that large of a question, and it was mostly just an add-on in case someone answered it before I found the answer in Google. Sorry. ^^;;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSLog() that filePath string.  I think you're trying to write to the directory itself, not to a file.

Try this instead:

```
filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.txt"];
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the file name you want to save? The method

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(...);
NSString *filePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
...
if(![fileString writeToFile:filePath ...
```

means you are saving the string into a file path *which has the same name as a folder*. This will of course fail. Please give it a name, e.g.

```
NSString* fileName = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];
if(![fileString writeToFile:fileName ...
```

and try again.

---

BTW, to use NSError:

```
NSError* theError = nil;
if(![fileString writeToFile:fileName ... error:&theError]) {
//                                             ^^^^^^^^^
  NSLog(@"Failed with reason %@", theError);
  // theError is autoreleased.
}
```

Comment: Ah.  I probably should've just looked straight up at the documentation for NSError.  I have a tendency to go googling and reading forums for information on how to use things before checking the documentation.