# Writing string to a file in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-io

I have few `NSString` objects that I want to add to a file. How can I do that.

The options I have explored so far are the

```
NSFilemanager - createFileAtPath:path contents:(NSData*)content
```

But I don't know how to transform my stringS into NSdata so I can write them in the file.

The other option is `NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath`  but I am not exactly clear with the syntax and the semantics of it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352665/write-nsstring-to-file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406516/failure-to-write-nsstring-to-file-on-ipad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is using `NSString`'s `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:` method: put your string objects into an `NSArray`, make a string out of them, and write the whole thing to a file:

```
NSString *firstString = @"Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
NSString *secondString = @"Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz";
NSArray *myStrings = @[firstString, secondString];
NSString *bigString = [myStrings componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
NSError *error = null;
[bigString writeToFile:@"filename"
            atomically:NO
              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                 error:&error];
```